# Why does SparkSQL always return out of range value when accessing any value in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, mariadb

I'm trying to access my MariaDB database in Spark to perform SQL queries on it.
It does successfully print the schema of the table, so the connection is working, but whenever I try to access any column or value inside the database I always get out of range exceptions:
java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column  : value canonical

The full log and stacktrace is below.

I can access the database outside Spark and successfully get the values of the database.
Moreover, I've tried using deprecated classes such as SparkSQLContext to access the database with similar results.

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // parse commandline parameters, get database properties
    val commandLineParser = new CommandLineParser()
    val commandLineParameters = commandLineParser.parseCommandLineParameters(args)
    val databaseProperties = PropertiesParser.readPropertiesFile(commandLineParameters.configFilePath)

    if (commandLineParameters.sparkSupport) {

      val spark =
      if (commandLineParameters.localMode) {
        SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("Spark Benchmark CLI")
          .config("spark.master", "local")
          .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/opt/spark-apps/spark-apps/mariadb-java-client-2.4.1.jar")
          .getOrCreate()
      } 

      // For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
      import spark.implicits._

      // connect
      Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
      val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseProperties.jdbcURL, databaseProperties.user, databaseProperties.password)
      connection.isClosed

      // Spark likes working with properties, hence we create a properties object
      val connectionProperties = new Properties()
      connectionProperties.put("user", s"${databaseProperties.user}")
      connectionProperties.put("password", s"${databaseProperties.password}")
      connectionProperties.put("driver", s"${commandLineParameters.databaseDriver}")

      val table = spark.read.jdbc(databaseProperties.jdbcURL, commandLineParameters.table, connectionProperties)
      table.printSchema() // this does successfully print the schema
      table.show() // this is where the exceptions are created
    } else {
        // some code that accesses the database successfully outside spark
    }

  }
}
```

I expect to be able to run SQL queries inside Spark without any out of range value exceptions.

The full log and stacktrace of what is actually happening:
https://gist.github.com/Zethson/7e3f43cd80daac219704df25cccd68fa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colleague of mine figured it out. It's a bug in Spark/MariaDB Connector:
References: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-421
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25013

I solved it by replacing mariadb in the DB Url with mysql.